# Rails Model Validations for Length and Numericality doesn't accept numbers starting with Zero

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have field `zip_code` in my table.I have provided validations for the field in the corresponding model as follows :

```
validates :zip_code, :length => { :minimum => 5, :maximum => 6 }, :numericality => true, allow_blank: true
```

The field is an integer in the Table.When i try to input a value like **'01234'** it doesnot accept it and gives an error like this:

```
zip code is too short (minimum is 5 characters)
```

It would be really helpful if someone can throw some light into this problem.

Comment: numbers don't have leading zeros.

Comment: 01234 is 1234 in number.

Comment: what should i do for it to accept leading zeros?I mean it should get saved as 01234

Comment: not store it or validate it as an integer.

Comment: @SoorajChandu maybe you don't need to validate it as a number but string instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You see, **zip_code** should not be a number. It should be a string with the format of a number. Like the guys commented in your question, you need to change your zip_code column to be of string type. Write a new migration for it:

```
rails g migration change_model_zip_code_type
```

Then in the migration:

```
def change
  change_column :my_table, :zip_code, :string
end
```

Then type in your console:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Now you can validate zip code as a numerical string:

```
validates :zip_code, :length => { :minimum => 5, :maximum => 6 }, :format => { with: /[0-9]+/ }
```

Comment: That wont work @Tiago,still gives the same validation error :(

Answer (score 2):

Can you try with the following code:

```
validates_length_of :zip_code, :in => 5..6, :allow_blank => true
```

Comment: That wont work bro..the issue was in the db design..as the field was integer..it will get saved without the leading zero..changing it to string was the fix for it..thanks for your answer